# Conversion from 600 Vdc to low voltage. Easy unregulated solution?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-voltage

On the new revision of our robot, we might switch to 600 Vdc motors (and therefore 600 Vdc supply voltage).

The problem is generating the low voltage rails (mainly 24 V and 48 V) for the internal electronics and tools. The goal is to have 1000-2000 W in total on the low voltage rails, with at least 500 W on each (24 V and 48 V).

With current robot, this was easily done, as supply voltage was lower, so there are many off-the-shelf modules available.

NB: either I can generate both low voltage rails with 2 isolated converters (and connect the grounds from 24 V and 48 V together), or I can use a single (more powerful) isolated converter (to either 24 or 48 V) and then generate the second rail with a non isolated converter.

For now, I see the following options:

1. Find an of-the-shelf DC/DC regulator accepting 600 Vdc input and outputting either 24 V or 48 V. So far, I found none that will fit into the limited space available (with <400 V inputs, it's easy to find). I keep looking for it.
2. Make a custom DC/DC converter directly on my PCB: not sure if this is something reasonable to try knowing that I have no experience in designing power DC/DCs (so far, I always used modules with just a few external components at most).
3. Same as 2, but hiring a contractor. Does anyone have a guesstimate how many days/weeks it takes to design such converter for someone with experience?
4. Convert down the input voltage in a non regulated way (providing or not isolation), then doing a second stage of regulated DC/DC conversion with lower input voltage (so plenty of modules available). I found one fixed ratio (1/16) converter from Vicor doing this, but is is very hard to source (no stock from authorized resellers, so either buying from brokers, or 32 weeks lead time). I found nothing else so far.
5. Same as 4, but doing the non regulated step down myself (nb: the quality of the output can be really poor: if the input range 500-650 V is mapped anywhere in the 10-60 V range, with ripple <10 V, it's fine for me). Is this something reasonably easy to do? If so, what typologies should I investigate?

So the core of my question is:

A. Which approache(s) seem most likely to success?

B. Is approach 5 something rather easy do get right, or is it nearly as hard as doing a regulated voltage controller?

PS: If you think some more precise specifications are useful, feel free to ask

Comment: What are your power requirements for the 24V and 48V rails? For something low power (sub 100W total) you could fairly easily do a flyback with a handful of parts and have something like the TI WebBench or ST DesignSuite do most of the design work for you. Higher power will lead to higher complexity though.

Comment: Nothing 600V >1kW is easy.

Comment: minimal requirement are 500W@24V + 400W@48V. Some more would be nice

Comment: Sorry, didn't see they specified 1-2kW power. For those levels you're looking at a much more complex design. 600V makes it tricky too as that cuts it close for 650V FETs.

Comment: Googling "600v dc input 48v output" I get a bunch of DC-DCs that would fit the bill, none of them cheap or compact of course [example](https://www.dwe-oss.eu/product/600v-to-48v-dc-dc-converter-1200w/). Could also use a 400V three phase input AC-DC if the PFC doesn't freak out with DC input.

Comment: Actually ask Vicor Power (not browse their catalog), you're not going to be able to make one of these better yourself first time without an unreal budget.

Comment: What protective features, EMC, etc.? Depending on if you find someone with experience in this range or not, I would expect upper four figures USD minimum to engineer. Safety issues at this voltage and DC are quite serious, which are relevant for anything else you have hooked into that system as well.

Comment: streetcars run at that sort of voltage, there should be modules around

Comment: @bobflux : for your example, the price tag is perfectly fine for me. The volume is already a bit too much (without the volume constraints, there a some around). But I will keep looking

Comment: @TimWilliams : I haven't digged much into protective features, but I think there won't be much : the power source is a "lab supply" (so no overshoots, current limiting, ...). The robot is the only thing powered by the 600V source, so conducted EMC is not an issue, and radiated EMC should be fine also (metal casing arround the electronics, and no sensitive analog circuits inside) as long as it is not insanely high.

Comment: It's your submarine robot? Maybe you need a module that can be cooled with cold plate instead of air then? https://www.vicorpower.com/dc-dc/isolated-fixed-ratio/bus-converter-module

Comment: Yes, it's still the submarine robot. Conduction cooling is fine for me. And the module you linked is the one I found so far (well, I found a similar component for 1000W at another manufacturer, but a little bit bigger, and doesn't seem easier to source). I keep looking

Comment: What's the source of the 600V bus?

Comment: An isolated AC/DC converter (like a lab supply, with adjustable voltage, current limit and power limit). And a 8 ohms 1.1µH cable in between